# Regex pattern to replace ampersand with special character

Tags: java, regex, for-loop, ampersand

I need to replace `https://9S&Re` with `https://9S#Re` so that I can avoid split logic. My objective is it get key as "user_image" and value as `"https://9S&Re"`. But when I use split with '&' it gives me wrong results. So I am trying for regex pattern which will check between &*& if there is not equals inbetween means there is an ampersand symbol in the one of the query value. Any help is really appreciated.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;

    public class OAuthTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                //HashMap paramHashMap=new HashMap();           
                List<NameValuePair> args2= URLEncodedUtils.parse("tool=canvas&tool_guid=8314&user_image=https://9S&Re&launch_presentation_document_target=iframe", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                for (NameValuePair arg:args2)
                    System.out.println(arg.getName()+"="+arg.getValue().replaceAll("#","&"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop, are you trying to replace & with #? Your arguments are switched.